# Brit Avraham commentry on Yalkut Shimoni

Tags: jewish-books, midrash, commentaries

Does anyone know if the Brit Avraham commentry on Yalkut Shimoni, Leviticus remez 137 is available online? (First published 1586.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can find it on Hebrewbooks. The edition on Vayikra can be found [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/6817).